# use external functions in the componentDidMount() and pass an element of the state to them as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a big application in React-Native and I have **a lot of duplicate functions** in the code.
So **I created a file** called function.js which could **contain all my duplicate functions**. Like queries on the local database, remote data base...

**So I pretty much got the job done. However I have a problem.**

This two functions must be used one after the other. 
**The first** one does an **update of the state** to get a **user id** from local database. 
**The second** one, asks information from the **remote database** with the **user id** retrieved by the first function **in parameters**.

**When both calls are in the componentdidmount element, unfortunately it doesn't work !!**

The **update time of the state** by the first function is **too slow** compared to the execution of the second function. 
**The second function gets an "undefined"** parameter when it is executed. because the state is not updated by the first function for the moment.

- If I put the second function in componentDidUpdate() it works but it runs in a loop so it's not a solution either.
- I also don't want to trigger the execution of the second function at the end of the first one in the external file. It would make the functions not autonomous from each other.
- And I think that the solution of a timeout() is not very good either, even if we could work with it.

**Example code :**

**It's the content of my App.js file that imports the Function.js file containing all my functions**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetchUser, prepareUserData } from 'bitcoin/Functions/Function'


export default class Profile extends Component {

  state = {
    user_id: "",
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    fetchUser.call(this);
    prepareUserData.call(this, this.state.user_id)
  }

render{
 return (<View></View>)
}
```

**This is the content of my Function.js file which contains functions that are duplicated in my application.**

```
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
import axios from "axios";

const db = SQLite.openDatabase("db.db");


/* #############################################################################
User data retrieval function in the local database
##############################################################################*/
export function fetchUser () {
  let query = "select * from ?";
  let params = [];
  db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
      query,
      params,
      (_, { rows: { _array } }) => {
        this.setState({user_id: _array[0].user_id})
      },
      function(tx, err) {
        console.log("Erreur" + err);
      }
    );
  });
}

/* #############################################################################
User data retrieval function in the remote database
##############################################################################*/
export function prepareUserData(userID) {
    let userConnect = new FormData();
    userConnect.append("id", userID);

    console.log(userConnect)
    const url =
      "https://*************/rest_api/React_native_api/appmobile_profile";

    axios
      .post(url, userConnect)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        if(res.status === 200){
        this.setState(
          {
            user_pseudo: res.data.pseudo,
            [ ... ]
            user_lastName: res.data.last_name,
           },);
       }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Erreuur", err);
      });
  }
```

I've tried a lot of things with async componentDidMount(), await myfunc(), creating asynchronous functions in my function file ...
But I can't find solutions. I could do otherwise but I find the problem really interesting.
I think there is a way to optimize my use of react native.
Thank you for your various feedbacks. Have a nice day.

Comment: This is a standard case of callbacks but I don't know exactly how you do it in react-native. Have you explored callbacks as a solution to your problem?

Comment: Your second function needs the first function to be resolved, so you have to call them one after another. Second, you probably shouldn't `setState` in shared functions, you should just return (async) values from them. Call the second function in `then` of the first async call.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your response. I don't have a good knowledge of callbacks. I just found a solution to the problem quite elegantly. I'll post it quickly, once formatted.
Thank you for your reactivity and your different answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Okay, so I've come up with a effective solution to this problem.**
I don't know much about promise and yet it seems to be a key for a lot element in react-native and javascript in general.
I'll share my code. Hopefully it can be useful to someone in the future! thank you for your prompt return and see you soon!

**To make it work I used:**

- The Promise Object `new Promise(function(resolve,reject)`
- Creation of a dynamic SQL query by adding parameters when calling the function.

**File App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { selectFromTable, prepareUserData } from 'bitcoin/Functions/Function'


export default class Profile extends Component {

  state = {
    user_data: "",
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    selectFromTable('user', ['*']).then((result) => {
      this.setState({ user_data: result.rows._array[0] },() => 
       {prepareUserData.call(this, this.state.user_data.user_id)})
    })
  }

render{
 return (<View></View>)
}
```

**File Function.js**

```
export function selectFromTable(table_name, selected_columns, conditions, callback) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            let db_cmd = `SELECT ${selected_columns} FROM ${table_name}`;
            db.transaction((tx, err) => {
                tx.executeSql(db_cmd, [], (tx, res) => {
                    resolve(res);
                },
                function(tx, err) {
                  console.log("Error" + err);
                }
                );
            });
        });
    }

export function prepareUserData(userID) {
   let userConnect = new FormData();
    userConnect.append("id", userID);
    const url =
          "https://**********/**********/appmobile_profile";

        axios
          .post(url, userConnect)
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            if(res.status === 200){
            this.setState(
              {
                user_pseudo: res.data.pseudo,
                user_cellphone: res.data.cellphone,
                user_callingCode: res.data.calling_code,
               });
            };
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error", err);
          });
      }
```